# Capture status after making a stripe api charge

Tags: php, api

I am looking for the php code syntax to capture if the call was successful or failed to stripe API. I need to capture one of the objects property to determine this but I am not sure what the best approach is.
Here's a sample response from a successful ACH api charge. I am looking for the php code syntax to capture if call was successful or failed

```
Stripe\Charge Object
(
[id] => py_1EFlRJBuwnzOEo57Poikh194
[object] => charge
[amount] => 50
[amount_refunded] => 0
[application] => 
[application_fee] => 
[application_fee_amount] => 
[balance_transaction] => txn_1EFlRJBuwnzOEo57dupt8SWp
[captured] => 1
[created] => 1553015365
[currency] => usd
[customer] => cus_Ec6cAdg6N2yYcF
[description] => 
[destination] => 
[dispute] => 
[failure_code] => 
[failure_message] => 
[fraud_details] => Array
    (
    )

[invoice] => 
[livemode] => 
[metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
    (
    )

[on_behalf_of] => 
[order] => 
[outcome] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
    (
        [network_status] => approved_by_network
        [reason] => 
        [risk_level] => not_assessed
        [seller_message] => Payment complete.
        [type] => authorized
    )

[paid] => 
[payment_intent] => 
[receipt_email] => 
[receipt_number] => 
[receipt_url] => https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1E8sOiBuwnzOEo57/py_1EFlRJBuwnzOEo57Poikh194/rcpt_EjDtGP7iknHI9RCBJ3iUODNC6bVBVyM
[refunded] => 
[refunds] => Stripe\Collection Object
    (
        [object] => list
        [data] => Array
            (
            )

        [has_more] => 
        [total_count] => 0
        [url] => /v1/charges/py_1EFlRJBuwnzOEo57Poikh194/refunds
    )

[review] => 
[shipping] => 
[source] => Stripe\BankAccount Object
    (
        [id] => ba_1E8sTZBuwnzOEo57MKqXEvb7
        [object] => bank_account
        [account_holder_name] => Rassi Stern
        [account_holder_type] => individual
        [bank_name] => STRIPE TEST BANK
        [country] => US
        [currency] => usd
        [customer] => cus_Ec6cAdg6N2yYcF
        [fingerprint] => 9l7up0pswCYSO7eu
        [last4] => 6789
        [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
            (
            )

        [routing_number] => 110000000
        [status] => verified
    )

[source_transfer] => 
[statement_descriptor] => 
[status] => pending
[transfer_data] => 
[transfer_group] => 
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the Stripe PHP library?

I implemented something like this:

```
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $amount, // in pence - min 30p
        "currency" => $currency,
        "description" => $description,
        "statement_descriptor" => $statementDescriptor,
        "source" => $token,
        "metadata" => array (
            'code' => $code
        ),
        "receipt_email" => $email
    ));
    $success = true;
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $success = false;
    // Some other stuff to capture the reason for failure and tell the user etc.
}
```

If you're not using their library, it's probably worth investigating it: there are a lot of varying reasons why a payment could succeed or fail, so looking through that massive Charge Object for the answer may not 100% yield the results you want.

Comment: I am using the library. I just simulated an error by sending amount below 50 cents. Instead of getting into the catch I got the error on my page. Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Amount must be at least 50 cents'

Comment: here is my code: try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                 "amount" => $replenish_amount * 100,
                 "currency" => "usd",
                  "customer" => $stripe_id
                 ]);
                 $success = true;
                 echo 'success';
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
     $success = false;
     echo 'false';
    }

Comment: @Rillus Setting your own boolean value won't actually determine if the charge was successful, only that your code executed without an error. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the value of the "paid" OR "status" parameters from the charge object.

```
$success = json_encode($charge->paid); // Expected value = true
$success = json_encode($charge->status); // Expected value = succeeded
```

Then you can do your check:

```
if($success) { // or $success == "succeeded" depending on which array key you go for.
    // Payment succeeded! Do something...
} else {
    print_r(json_encode($charge->failure_message));
    // Do something else...
}
```

The code may also work without json_encode(), I've found that my code is less buggy by using json_encode.

This is as per the Stripe API Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create